# Trying to program a batch file that writes one of 16 different words to a file depending on a 16-way choice

Tags: batch-file

Here's my horrible code.
I'm pretty new to this, as you can tell.
It's supposed to make writing down the picture-based passwords in an old game easier,and have customisable codes, but it takes up way too much space.

```
@echo off
SET code1=dog        
SET code2=cat        
SET code3=hamster    
SET code4=chicken    
SET code5=cow        
SET code6=horse      
SET code7=lizard     
SET code8=snake      
SET code9=frog       
SET code10=llama      
SET code11=sheep      
SET code12=rabbit     
SET code13=chinchilla 
SET code14=monkey     
SET code15=human      
SET code16=alien      
:CODE
SET /a n+=1
ECHO 1:%code1%2:%code2%3:%code3%4:%code4%5:%code5%6:%code6%7:%code7%8:%code8%
ECHO Q:%code9%W:%code10%E:%code11%R:%code12%T:%code13%Y:%code14%U:%code15%I:%code16%
CHOICE /c 12345678QWERTYUI /n
set thing=%errorlevel%
if %thing%==1 echo %code1%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==2 echo %code2%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==3 echo %code3%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==4 echo %code4%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==5 echo %code5%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==6 echo %code6%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==7 echo %code7%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==8 echo %code8%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==9 echo %code9%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==10 echo %code10%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==11 echo %code11%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==12 echo %code12%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==13 echo %code13%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==14 echo %code14%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==15 echo %code15%>passwords.txt
if %thing%==16 echo %code16%>passwords.txt
if n lss 8 goto CODE
rem change this number for length of password
echo done
```

What it's supposed to do is output 8 of the words to one line of a text file, i.e. pressing "1q2w3e4r" would output "dog frog cat llama hamster sheep chicken rabbit" to the text file.

Comment: Did you have a specific question?  If you do, please help us focus on what it is that you need help with.

Comment: I think he want to know how to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is:

```
@echo off & Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion

:: Set the codes
Set "Codes=dog cat hamster chicken cow horse lizard snake frog llama sheep rabbit chinchilla monkey human alien"
:: Set the Choice Options
Set "Opts=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 Q W E R T Y U I"

:: Set up the Code Variables
For %%C in (%Codes%) Do (
    Set /A "CodeIndex+=1"
    Set "Code!CodeIndex!=%%C"
)

:: Set up the Choice Letter Variables
For %%O in (%Opts%) Do (
    Set /A "OptIndex+=1"
    Set "Opt!OptIndex!=%%O"
)

:Menu
:: Display the menu
For /L %%N in (1, 1, 8) Do (<nul Set /P "=!Opt%%N!:!Code%%N! ")
Echo+
For /L %%N in (9, 1, 16) Do (<nul Set /P "=!Opt%%N!:!Code%%N! ")
Echo+

CHOICE /C "%Opts: =%" /n

:: Return
:: If %ERRORLEVEL% lss 9 (goto :MENU)

:: Write the selected code
Echo !Code%ERRORLEVEL%!>".\Passwords.txt"

:END
Exit /B 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your counting loop is broken, and I don't know how it is supposed to work, so I removed it entirely.
I also removed the redirection to the password file to make it easy to see what is happening - it can be added back easily enough.

The code below readily adpapts to additions or subtractions to the code word list. The list need only be updated in one place. I added a few more entries to show how easy it is, and to show that it need not be multiples of 8.

I assumed you wanted the trailing spaces of the code words to be stripped - they are only there for proper menu spacing.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "n=0"
set "keys="
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set $prompt 2^>nul') do set "%%A="
for %%A in (
  "1:dog        "
  "2:cat        "
  "3:hamster    "
  "4:chicken    "
  "5:cow        "
  "6:horse      "
  "7:lizard     "
  "8:snake      "
  "Q:frog       "
  "W:llama      "
  "E:sheep      "
  "R:rabbit     "
  "T:chinchilla "
  "Y:monkey     "
  "U:human      "
  "I:alien      "
  "A:godzilla   "
  "S:orc        "
  "D:medussa    "
) do (
  set /a "p=n/8,n+=1"
  for %%P in (!p!) do set "$prompt%%P=!$prompt%%P!%%~A"
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%B in (%%A) do (
    set "keys=!keys!%%B"
    set "code!n!=%%C"
  )
)
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%A in ('set $prompt') do echo %%B
choice /c !keys! /n
for %%N in (%errorlevel%) do echo !code%%N!
```